# New users posting comments as answers

Tags: discussion

On [What do you call the process of combining two words to create a new one?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91306/what-do-you-call-the-process-of-combining-two-words-to-create-a-new-one), a new user posted as [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102454/2637) something that was deleted by a mod, but which might even have picked up a few *upvotes* if it had been posted as a comment.

For those without the rep to see it, [Clayton wright](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/36848/clayton-wright) posted **Two words combined .... = Tword**

As it happens, I was laboriously typing a message to the new user, welcoming him to ELU, but warning that his answer/comment wasn't likely to survive long. In fact, it was deleted before I could post my comment.

---

My question is: in such situations, should it be standard practice either for such deletions to always be accompanied by "stock text" explaining the reason, or for the answer text to be converted to a comment? Given the spate of recent complaints about ELU being "unwelcoming", it seems to me we're shooting ourselves in the foot if we don't do something like that.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you here. But if the purpose of the "stock text" is to provide feedback to the user, isn't it pointless as s/he will never see it?

Comment: I don't know how much rep you need to see deleted answers, and I don't know if the OP can perhaps *always* see his own deletions. But if not, the mod could always add another comment before or after the one containing the "moved" text, telling the OP what's been done, and why.

Comment: Comments always appear in the notification thingy, even if the answer has been deleted. So provided the comment is short enough not to be truncated, it can be seen. It's 10k to see deleted answers, and I don't believe that users *can* see their own answers when they have been deleted; that's come up here before. I don't see why that's the case.

Comment: @coleopterist: I believe that all users do see their own deleted answers.

Comment: @Marthaª Ah. I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

When I first joined just last week, I had to earn a certain amount of rep before I could even add or vote on comments, so I could only put answers in the boxes like this one. When I realised I could then do comments, I now do where I think it's appropriate. Other new users may try to comment too, but can't until they've earned however much rep it is.

Comment: In the circumstances I almost hate to say it, but this looks more like a comment than an answer than can be meaningfully voted on!

Comment: I think the point to that is that you're not supposed to leave comments until you have enough rep. But that empty box is just calling out to be filled! Well, anyway, you're not supposed to leave something that is not a answer in the answer box.

Comment: Absolutely.  I am sure that there a good reasons for limiting a new user's ability to add comments, but I'm not sure if people realize that this practice encourages the mis-use of answers. I imagine that user's join a community because they want to participate and contribute, but the only way they can do so is to post answers.  Is anyone surprised that they do so?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [per this answer on the *meta* meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86377/153019), all users can see their own deleted answers, presumably including any comments that were deleted along with the answer. The deletion automatically adds a link to the "why was my post deleted" section of the FAQ, but it certainly can't hurt to add a "Welcome to ELU..." type of comment as well, on the premise that we need to take every opportunity to be more friendly and welcoming if this site isn't to degenerate into a den of grumpy old descriptivists.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps it's deleted *questions* which users can't see, then.

Comment: Actually it can hurt; an *automatic* 'Welcome to ELU' when your answer has been deleted is both hypocritical and patronising, as at least one 'sufferer' has commented recently.  If somebody (mod or otherwise) is prepared to take the time to explain why *this particular post* was deleted, that is both kind and helpful; but it can't be mandated, and can't really be automated in any way that will help a new user.

Comment: @TimLymington: I wasn't suggesting an *automatic* comment. I agree, there's really no way for an automatic comment to come across as anything better than patronizing. I'm saying that it's OK to go ahead and add a comment to a non-answer that you know is going to be deleted, because the OP *will* be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way/should there be a way of allowing migration of new user comment 'answers' to a comment, on the question rather than another answer, as that is probably a crapshoot to discern, rather than downvoting/removing?

To a new user who hasn't fully understood the FAQ, it can appear harsh and unwelcoming, as others have pointed out to just be downvoted and deleted for trying to help, however misguided. Allowing migration to comments allows their potentially positive contribution to remain if it cannot be fleshed out into a fuller answer.

Comment: I believe moderators can convert answers to comments, but as far as I know, there is no community mechanism to do so.

Comment: @choster - I don't mean to state the obvious, but an answer can be flagged, using the option "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." Or, one could selection the "Other" option, and simply type "Should be a comment." So, there's no direct mechanism, but there's still a way to throw the opinion out there.

Comment: @J.R. thanks, I have been using this option quite a lot since I was made aware of it!

Comment: @J.R. Unless I’m mistaken, that flagging option puts the flagged answer in a queue accessible by all high-rep users (not sure what the cut-off is exactly), but unless you’re a mod, you can only review the flag by editing the answer or adding a vote to 1) keep it as it is, or 2) have it deleted. If no mod happens to see the flag (or the answer itself), there is no way for it to be converted to a comment. The flag’s description is quite poorly worded, if you ask me. If you think the flag should be a comment, you basically have to flag it for moderator attention, not as “Not an answer”.

Comment: @Janus - I think you might be right. Either way, though, a mod will eventually see it, and fix it if necessary. I guess which option you select depends on if you want to "quietly" flag it, or do so in a way that lets other high-rep users weigh in with their opinions as well.

Comment: @J.R. A mod will not necessarily see it—if five users get to it first and get it deleted, it disappears from the review queue and the mods won't see it—I think.

Comment: @Janus - The mods see posts that have been flagged, even after they have disappeared from the review queue—I think. (Seriously, I _think_ that's how it works, but I'm not 100% sure.)